# How Can I retrive data from Google Ads API

Tags: python, ssl, https, connection, google-ads-api

(1) In the area I am now, Google website is not visitable because of the Great Firewall. But I am using Clash for Windows and I could access and visit Google website. It works well on my browser.

(2)I am testing Google Ads API with simple function in Python like the following through Jupyter Notebook which is installed on my Windows 10 laptop:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException

  
# Define the main function
def main(client, customer_id):
    ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")

    query = """
        SELECT
            campaign.id,
            campaign.name
        FROM campaign
        ORDER BY campaign.id
    """

    # Issues a search request using streaming.
    stream = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id=customer_id, query=query)

    # Iterate through the results and print them
    for batch in stream:
        for row in batch.results:
            print(
                f"Campaign with ID {row.campaign.id} and name "
                f"{row.campaign.name}"
            )

# Load Google Ads client from storage
# Replace "PATH/TO/YOUR/google-ads.yaml" with the actual path to your file
googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(path=r"C:\Users\tomxi\google-ads.yaml", version="v15")

# Get customer ID from user input (optional)
# Replace with your desired method of obtaining the customer ID
customer_id = "xxxxxxxxxx"

# Call the main function
try:
    main(googleads_client, customer_id)
except GoogleAdsException as ex:
    print(
        f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status '
        f'"{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:'
    )
    for error in ex.failure.errors:
        print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
        if error.location:
            for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                print(f"\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}")
    sys.exit(1)
```

(3)I got the error:

```
[TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '\[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING\] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)')))][1]
```

(4)I guess the Google Ads API employs some route or something else which is not used or controlled by the Clash for Window on my laptop. I am not sure how to check and change it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the script on colab. But you're referencing the config file on your local machine.

You need to mount your Google Drive and upload any files there if you want it to work in colab.

However, I would strongly advise against hosting your config file on colab, as it contains extremely sensitive credentials, including your Google Ads developer key and your personal Google account refresh/access tokens.

Comment: Hi, Dave, Thanks for your response. I ran the code and got the error message on my Windows PC other than Colab. I have delete the link to Colab since it mileads people. Do you have any new idea on my question then?